# IronPython pyc.py -> .exe : How to compile a program that imports an external dll?

Tags: python, .net, dll, exe, ironpython

I am starting to use the pyc.py file to create a .exe file of my IronPython project. It seems that pyc.py cannot deal with programs that use external .net dlls. To be clear here are examples of something that worked and something that didn't:

program1.py :

```
print 'hello world'
raw_input('--->')
```

I managed to make a .exe file of program1.py which worked by using the following command:

```
ipy pyc.py /main:program1.py /target:exe
```

Now here is program2.py :

```
from clr import AddReferenceToFile
AddReferenceToFile ('myExternalDllForProgram2.dll')
raw_input('--->')
```

I managed to make a .exe file of program2.py using the same command that for program1.py. Problem is, the .exe file does not work (the result box writes a lot of things and fails at some point).

Of course, myExternalDllForProgram2.dll was put in the folder with the .exe file and its dll (and with these dlls as well: IronPython.dll, IronPython.Modules.dll, Microsoft.Scripting.Metadata.dll, Microsoft.Scripting.dll, Microsoft.Dynamic.dll)

Does any one have an idea of what could have gone wrong?

**---------EDIT---------**

I fixed all my problems and explained the 4 errors I had to overcome here : http://thesesergio.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/how-to-generate-and-use-a-exe-that-uses-net-dlls-with-ironpython-pyc-py/